# passing data to static table - not able to access TableViewCell cells value

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I am trying to build iOS app, where a view controller is calling (push) another view controller. In second view controller, I have static `TableViewController` with 1 section and 2 static cells.

Whenever I am accessing cells' elements, code throws an exception.

View Controller 2 is pushed by following code:

```
var destinationController = new EditAccountTableViewController(accounts[indexPath.Row]);
parentController.NavigationController.PushViewController(destinationController, true);`
```

EdditAccountTablewViewController class:

```
public partial class EditAccountTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    private Account account;

    public EditAccountTableViewController()
    {
        var loc = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("New", "");
        var loc2 = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("Account", "");
        Title = $"{loc} {loc2}";

        this.account = new Account();
        AccountNameCell.DetailTextLabel.Text = account.Name;
        AccountDescriptionCell.DetailTextLabel.Text = account.Description;
    }

    public EditAccountTableViewController(Account account)
    {
        var loc = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("Account", "");
        Title = $"{loc}";

        this.account = account;
        AccountNameCell.DetailTextLabel.Text = account.Name;
        AccountDescriptionCell.DetailTextLabel.Text = account.Description;
    }

    partial void SaveAccountButton_Activated(UIBarButtonItem sender)
    {
        if (account.Name != string.Empty)
        {
            Database.Instance.DataAccess.SaveModelItem<Account>(account);
        }
    }
}
```

`AccountNameCell` and `AccountDescriptionCell` are cells names. Cells are created in storyboard here:

[image]

Whenever I run the code, I get following exception:
[image]

It's clear to me, that exception is caused by `AccountNameCell` which is `null`. I do not understand though why it is `null` and nor how to solve it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using segue instead of pushing viewController, where I am leveraging prepareForSegue method. Here is the code which I am using:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

    if (segue.Identifier == "EditAccountSegue")
    {
        var secondViewController = segue.DestinationViewController as EditAccountTableViewController;
        var selectedPath = TableView.IndexPathForSelectedRow;
        var accountSource = TableView.Source as AccountsSettingSource;
        var account = accountSource.getItem(selectedPath.Row);
        secondViewController.Account = account;
    }
    else if (segue.Identifier == "AddAccountSegue")
    {
        var destinationController = segue.DestinationViewController as EditAccountTableViewController;
        destinationController.Account = new Account();
    }
}
```